# List<int> vs int list in F Sharp

Tags: list, generics, f#

Is there any difference between `List<int>` and `int list`?
For example, when I write a function

```
let somefn a : int list = a
```

and

```
let somefn2 a : List<int> = a
```

Returned value types differ with notation style, and even in the console output, when I invoke those functions, it shows two distinctly noted types

```
val it : int list = ...
```

and

```
val it : List<int> = ...
```

Although, logic and idea seems to be same, Interpreter/compiler interprets those two types in a different way.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To expand slightly on John Palmer's correct answer, here's an F# Interactive session that illustrates how `int list` and `List<int>` are synonyms, right up until the moment when they aren't. And note how there's also `list<int>` and `ResizeArray<int>` for extra confusion:

```
F# Interactive for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

> typeof<list<int>>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections"
> typeof<list<int>>.Name ;;     
val it : string = "FSharpList`1"
> typeof<List<int>>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections"
> typeof<List<int>>.Name ;;     
val it : string = "FSharpList`1"
> typeof<int list>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections"
> typeof<int list>.Name ;;     
val it : string = "FSharpList`1"
> typeof<ResizeArray<int>>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "System.Collections.Generic"
> typeof<ResizeArray<int>>.Name ;;     
val it : string = "List`1"
- 
- printfn "Now we'll open System.Collections.Generic. Watch what happens."
- ;;
Now we'll open System.Collections.Generic. Watch what happens.
val it : unit = ()
> open System.Collections.Generic ;;
> typeof<list<int>>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections"
> typeof<list<int>>.Name ;;
val it : string = "FSharpList`1"
> typeof<List<int>>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "System.Collections.Generic"
> typeof<List<int>>.Name ;;     
val it : string = "List`1"
> typeof<int list>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections"
> typeof<int list>.Name ;;
val it : string = "FSharpList`1"
> typeof<ResizeArray<int>>.Namespace ;;
val it : string = "System.Collections.Generic"
> typeof<ResizeArray<int>>.Name ;;     
val it : string = "List`1"
```

So `List<int>` with an uppercase L will be the F# list type (an immutable linked list with a head pointer, which has O(1) head access and prepending, but O(N) tail access and appending) if you haven't opened the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. But if you *have*, then suddenly `List<int>` resolves to the .Net `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` class, which is a *mutable* data structure with O(1) lookups anywhere, amortized O(1) appends, but O(N) prepends. So it really *matters* which one you're using.

To be on the safe side, if you intend to use the F# list structure, I'd write it as either `int list` (my preference since it reads like English) or `list<int>` (which some people prefer since it reads like C#). Neither of those will suddenly acquire a different meaning when you open a .Net namespace; they will continue to refer to the F# list structure. And avoid using `List<int>` to refer to F# lists; only use that when you have opened  the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace and you intend to get a .Net `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` instance. Finally, note that in F#, `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` has a type alias available *without* opening the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. By default, without needing to open any namespaces, you can access this type under the name `ResizeArray<T>`.

Summary:

**Safe type names**:

- `int list` and `list<int>` (always refer to the F# singly-linked list type)
- `ResizeArray<int>` (always refers to the C# `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` type)

**Unsafe type names** because their meaning changes depending on what namespace you've opened:

- `List<int>` (refers to the F# singly-linked list type at first, but *changes meaning* to the C# type if you open the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace). As a general rule, don't use this type name; if you want this type in F#, use `ResizeArray<int>` instead.

Comment: Maybe add a part to say that `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` as also an alias `ResizeArray` and so for that specific thing one doesn't need to open the namespace

Comment: @Sehnsucht - Good idea! Done.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference, there is a type alias.

Except under one case, where you have run

```
 open System.Collections.Generic
```

Which has its own list type

Answer (score 4):

- Generally, for generic types with one parameter, `TypeParameter GenericType` is equivalent to `GenericType<TypeParameter>`.
- The F# immutable list type declared in FSharp.Core is in scope with two names by default: `List` and `list`. It has one type parameter, so `int list`, `list<int>`, `int List`, and `List<int>` are equivalent.
- `System.Collections.Generic` has a different `List<'T>` type, which has the more suitable alias `ResizeArray` in F#. If you open `System.Collections.Generic`, `List` refers to this mutable, array-wrapping type.

To avoid confusion, it is customary to not use `List` with a capital `L` to refer to a type in F#. Instead, `list` with a lowercase `l` is used for the FP-originating, immutable, singly-linked lists, while `ResizeArray` is used to refer to the OO-style mutable collection. Most people also stick to the different styles `int list` versus `ResizeArray<int>` and avoid the other combinations.

As for type information, IDEs and similar sometimes attempt to display types in the way they were declared, as there are often many ways to refer to the same type. This does not imply a difference in behavior.